# React lodash Remove not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a `state` that contains objects. I also have a delete api that removes an object from the `state` based on a `object property`. Here is the code:

```
deleteItem(item_to_delete){
    const del_item = _.find(this.state.bucket_list, bucklistitem => bucklistitem.name === item_to_delete);
    fetch(url(this.props.api) + '/' + del_item._id, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    _.remove(this.state.bucket_list, bucketlistitem => bucketlistitem.name === item_to_delete);
    this.setState({ bucket_list: this.state.bucket_list });
}
```

However I understand I am treating the `state` as mutable currently which is bad. Therefore, I want to change my code by creating a copy of the `state`, changing the copy, and `setState`. Here is the code:

```
deleteItem(item_to_delete){
    let bucket_list_copy = Object.assign({}, this.state.bucket_list); //Copy of state
    const del_item = _.find(bucket_list_copy, bucklistitem => bucklistitem.name === item_to_delete);
    fetch(url(this.props.api) + '/' + del_item._id, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    _.remove(bucket_list_copy, { name: item_to_delete });
    this.setState({ bucket_list: bucket_list_copy });
}
```

However, although this deletes the object from the Database, it doesn't remove it from the `copied list`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your second argument on remove different on the two versions?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong here. 1. where is your deleteItem method called within the React lifecycle ? 2. Have you actually debugged the code and doublechecked that the item is removed from the list before setting the new state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
_.remove(bucket_list_copy, {name: item_to_delete});
```

to this

```
_.remove(bucket_list_copy, bucketlistitem => bucketlistitem.name === item_to_delete);
```

If you look at [Lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove), remove doesn't accept an object as a second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip a couple steps with splice

```
const delItemIndex = _.findIndex(this.state.bucket_list, bucklistitem => bucklistitem.name === item_to_delete);
let newBucketList = this.state.bucket_list.splice(delItemIndex, 1);

fetch(url(this.props.api) + '/' + this.state.bucket_list[delItemIndex]._id, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});

this.setState({ bucket_list: newBucketList  });
```